# Follow-up: Eliminating partially overlapping parts of 2 vectors in R

Tags: r, regex, string, function, character

I want to drop the parts in `n1` character vector that ***partially (not fully) overlap*** with elements in `f1` formula.

For example, in `n1`, we see `"study_typecompare"` & `"study_typecontrol"` partially overlap with `study_type` in `f1`.

Thus in the `desired_output`, we want to drop the `"study_type"` part of them. Because other elements (ex. `factor(v_gi)`) in `n1` fully overlap with an element in `f1` or don't exist (ex. `intrcpt`) in `f1`, we leave them unchanged.

Is obtaining my `desired_output` (below) possible in BASE R or tidyvesrse?

I have tried the following, but it errounousely drops `v_gi` from within `factor(v_gi)`:

```
f1 <- gi ~ factor(v_gi) + study_type
n1 <- c("intrcpt","factor(v_gi)","study_typecompare","study_typecontrol")


fun1 <- function(fmla, vec) {
  
  v1 <- all.vars(fmla)
  v2 <- setdiff(vec, v1)
  v3 <- sub(paste(v1, collapse = "|"), "", v2)
  vec[vec %in% v2] <- v3
  vec
}
# EXAMPLE OF USE:
fun1(f1, n1)
# Current Output:
[1] "intrcpt"  "factor()" "compare"  "control"  ## Notice `factor()` has errounousely lost its`v_gi`

desired_output = c("intrcpt","factor(v_gi)","compare","control")
```

Comment: Could you give an example of a case where `n1`  _includes_  an element of `all.vars(fmla)` i.e. `length(intersect(vec, v1)) != 0` is `TRUE`?

Comment: @jay.sf, why is that important?

Comment: Just wasn't sure why the `setdiff`, maybe the code can be simplified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the `setdiff` line, `paste` a `^` as prefix to the strings, so in the `sub` it only matches the beginnings.

```
fun1 <- function(fmla, vec) {
  v1 <- all.vars(fmla)
  v2 <- setdiff(vec, v1)
  v1 <- paste0('^', v1)
  v3 <- sub(paste(v1, collapse = "|"), "", v2)
  vec[vec %in% v2] <- v3
  vec
}

fun1(f1, n1)
# [1] "intrcpt"      "factor(v_gi)" "compare"      "control"
```